# Applying Cantor's diagonal argument

Tags: proof-explanation, cardinals

I understand how Cantor's diagonal argument can be used to prove that the real numbers are uncountable. But I should be able to use this same argument to prove two additional claims: (1) that there is no bijection $X \to \mathcal{P}(X)$ and (2) that there are arbitrarily large cardinal numbers.

I don't understand how to apply the diagonal argument, or a variation of its logic, in this case. I know how to prove Cantor's theorem. I suppose there exists a surjection $f: X \to P(X)$, consider the set $B = \{x \in X \mid x \not \in f(x)\}$, argue that there has to exist $y \in X$ such that $f(y) = b$, and then show that $y \in B$ and $y \not \in B$ both give contradictions. To show that there are arbitrarily large cardinals, I take $\mathbb{N}$, $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$, $\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}))$, and continue ad infinitum.

Is there a way that I'm silently using the diagonal argument here? Or is there a different way to think of these arguments?

Comment: That set you consider ($B$) is exactly the diagonal argument.

Comment: I wonder if there *is* a sentence in the entirety of mathematics which contains the expression "ad infinitum" and which is also correct...

Comment: Ironically, if you consider the sequence $\{\beth_n\}_{n\in\Bbb N}$ defined recursively as $\beth_0:=\lvert\Bbb N\rvert$, $\beth_{n+1}=\lvert\mathcal P(\beth_n)\rvert$, you end up with a *bounded* sequence of cardinals (specifically, bounded above by $\beth_\omega:=\sup_{n\in\Bbb N}\beth_n=\left\lvert\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}\beth_n\right\rvert$)

Comment: As **Tan** already pointed out, your argument with the set $B$ **is** the diagonal argument proving that there is no surjection of $X$ onto $\wp(X)$. Since there is an obvious injection, this shows that $|\wp(X)|>|X|$, which in turn immediately implies that there are arbitrarily large cardinals.

Comment: Does it imply that there are arbitrarily large cardinals by taking successive power sets? If so, I completely understand.

Comment: Instead of saying the (meaningless?) "there are arbitrarily large cardinals", maybe say "there is no largest cardinal".

Comment: Yes, it does imply that there is no largest cardinal.

Answer (score 2):

Your solution to (2) is wrong. To show that there are arbitrarily large natural numbers divisible by $3$ we don't start with $0$, apply the successor function (or any increasing function), and hope for the best. We show that if $n$ is a number then one of $n+1,n+2,n+3$ is divisible by $3$ and all are strictly larger than $n$.

The same here. You're not supposed to iterate power sets from $\Bbb N$. How do you know that the sequence doesn't have an upper bound which is the largest cardinal? Instead, show that if $X$ is **any** set whatsoever, there is another set which has a strictly larger cardinality. For example, apply (1), but note that "there is no surjection from $X$ to $Y$" does not necessarily mean that $Y$ is *larger*, we also need to exhibit an injection from $X$ into $Y$.

Comment: This is very helpful, but could you explain why we also need to show an injection from $X$ into $Y$? I thought a lack of a surjection was sufficient.

Comment: Though it doesn't seem very difficult to do find an injection. I can just make $X \to \mathcal{P}(X)$ by $x \mapsto \{x\}$. I just don't understand why an injection is necessary.

Comment: It's the definition of "larger".

Comment: Is the idea that, in general, if there exists an injection $f: A \to B$, then $|A| \leq |B|$, but $|A| =|B|$ only if there is also a surjection, so we drop the equality and conclude $|A| < |B|$, in which case we say that $B$ is strictly larger than $A$?

Comment: No, $|A|=|B|$ if and only if there is a bijection.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say that $|A|=|B|$ if and only if that injective (or a injection) is also a surjection, hence a bijection.

Comment: Well, "that injection" is wrong, since that implies that every injection is a bijection. But that's only true for finite sets.

Comment: Would it be correct if I rephrased it as: "if there exists an injection $f: A \to B$ (which implies $|A| \leq |B|$) which is also a surjection, then $|A| = |B|$; but if none are, i.e., there are no surjections, then $|A| < |B|$?

Comment: No. In general, if you don't assume the axiom of choice, it is possible to have an injection and a surjection from $A$ to $B$, but no bijections. That is, $A$ is smaller than $B$, but it still maps onto $B$. Weird, I know, and usually people work with the axiom of choice, which makes all of these problems go away. But it's important to pay attention to the small details.

Comment: Interesting. Thank you for the help.